# Is 'float a = 3.0;' a correct statement?

Tags: c++, c++11

If I have the following declaration:

```
float a = 3.0 ;
```

is that an error? I read in a book that `3.0` is a `double` value and that I have to specify it as `float a = 3.0f`. Is it so?

Comment: The compiler will convert the double literal `3.0` into a float for you. The end result is indistinguishable from `float a = 3.0f`.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html is useful to read

Comment: @EdHeal: It is, but it's not particularly relevant to this question, which is about C++ rules.

Comment: Well, at the very least you need a `;` after.

Comment: @HotLicks it was pretty easy to edit the question and add the `;` like I just did.

Comment: 10 downvotes and not much in the comments to explain them, very discouraging. This is the OPs first question and if people feel this is worth 10 downvotes there should be some explanations. This is a valid question with non-obvious implications and many interesting things to learn from the answers and comments.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour - The OP also got 58 upvotes, which is far more than this question deserves.  I can't feel sorry for him.

Comment: @HotLicks it is not about feeling bad or good, sure it may seem unfair but that is life, they are unicorn points after all. Dowvotes surely are not to cancel out upvotes you don't like just like upvotes are not to cancel out downvotes you don't like. If people feel the question can be improved, surely a first time asker should get some feedback. I don't see any reason to downvote but I would like to know why others do although they are free to not say so.

Answer (score 159, accepted):

It is not an error to declare `float a = 3.0` : if you do, the compiler will convert the double literal 3.0 to a float for you.

---

However, you **should** use the float literals notation in specific scenarios.

1. **For performance reasons:**

   Specifically, consider:

   ```
   float foo(float x) { return x * 0.42; }
   ```

   Here the compiler will emit a conversion (that you will pay at runtime) for each returned value. To avoid it you should declare:

   ```
   float foo(float x) { return x * 0.42f; } // OK, no conversion required
   ```
2. **To avoid bugs when comparing results:**

   e.g. the following comparison fails :

   ```
   float x = 4.2;
   if (x == 4.2)
      std::cout << "oops"; // Not executed!
   ```

   We can fix it with the float literal notation :

   ```
   if (x == 4.2f)
      std::cout << "ok !"; // Executed!
   ```

   (Note: of course, [this is not how you should compare float or double numbers for equality in general](//stackoverflow.com/questions/17333/most-effective-way-for-float-and-double-comparison))
3. **To call the correct overloaded function (for the same reason):**

   Example:

   ```
   void foo(float f) { std::cout << "\nfloat"; }

   void foo(double d) { std::cout << "\ndouble"; }

   int main()
   {       
       foo(42.0);   // calls double overload
       foo(42.0f);  // calls float overload
       return 0;
   }
   ```
4. **[As noted by Cyber](//stackoverflow.com/a/25229947/3510483), in a type deduction context, it is necessary to help the compiler deduce a `float` :**

   In case of `auto` :

   ```
   auto d = 3;      // int
   auto e = 3.0;    // double
   auto f = 3.0f;   // float
   ```

   And similarly, in case of template type deduction :

   ```
   void foo(float f) { std::cout << "\nfloat"; }

   void foo(double d) { std::cout << "\ndouble"; }

   template<typename T>
   void bar(T t)
   {
         foo(t);
   }

   int main()
   {   
       bar(42.0);   // Deduce double
       bar(42.0f);  // Deduce float

       return 0;
   }
   ```

---

[**Live demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/266ec0198f8bc21d)

Comment: As for point 1, I would think that today's compilers were smart enough to recognise the run-time performance penalty they would create and treat both lines the same. What sense does it make to emit a conversion which is totally unnecessary? Then again, I have not measured, I am just guessing. As for point 2, floating-point comparions with `==` are always asking for trouble. Sooner or later during refactoring, `x` will be the result of some other floating-point operation, and then a supposed result of 4.2 will no longer be guaranteed to be equivalent to the literal `4.2f`.

Comment: @ChristianHackl Converting `4.2` to `4.2f` may have the side effect of setting the `FE_INEXACT` flag, depending on the compiler and system, and some (admittedly few) programs do care about which floating-point operations are exact, and which aren't, and test for that flag. This means that the simple obvious compile-time transformation alters the program's behaviour.

Comment: `float foo(float x) { return x*42.0; }` can be compiled to a single-precision multiplication, and was compiled so by Clang the last time I tried. However `float foo(float x) { return x*0.1; }` cannot be compiled to a single single-precision multiplication. It may have been a bit over-optimistic before this patch, but after the patch it should only combine conversion-double_precision_op-conversion to single_precision_op when the result is always the same. http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.compilers.llvm.cvs/167800/match=

Comment: @PascalCuoq indeed [godbolt](http://goo.gl/JI61u7) shows this exact result using both clang and gcc. So we end up with identical assembly for both. So I would say that the example in case 1 is not correct. That is a useful link by the way, I was looking for some details on why it was doing that.

Comment: @PascalCuoq Thanks for th details. I edited to 42.42 (I'm actually looking at a reference to know if compiler can or must, enforce this)

Comment: _"that you will pay at runtime"_ has anyone benchmarked this? Seems like something a compiler would have little trouble with optimizing it out.

Comment: Slipped past everyone that you were comparing floating point numbers for equality, float or double that's not a smart move.

Comment: If one wishes to compute a value which is one tenth of `someFloat`, the expression `someFloat * 0.1` will more accurate results than `someFloat * 0.1f`, while in many cases being cheaper than a floating-point division.  For example, (float)(167772208.0f*0.1) will correctly round to 16777220 rather than 16777222.  Some compilers may substitute a `double` multiply for a floating-point divide, but for those that don't (it's safe for many though not all values) the multiply may be a useful optimization, but only if performed with a `double` reciprocal.

Answer (score 22):

The compiler will turn any of the following literals into floats, because you declared the variable as a float.

```
float a = 3;     // converted to float
float b = 3.0;   // converted to float
float c = 3.0f;  // float
```

It would matter is if you used `auto` (or other type deducting methods), for example:

```
auto d = 3;      // int
auto e = 3.0;    // double
auto f = 3.0f;   // float
```

Comment: Types are also deduced when using templates, so `auto` is not the only case.

Answer (score 14):

Floating point literals without a suffix are of type *double*, this is covered in the draft C++ standard section `2.14.4` *Floating literals*:

> [...]The type of a floating literal is double unless explicitly specified by a suffix.[...]

so is it an error to assign `3.0` a *double literal* to a *float*?:

```
float a = 3.0
```

No, it is not, it will be converted, which is covered in section `4.8` *Floating point conversions*:

> A prvalue of floating point type can be converted to a prvalue of
>   another floating point type. If the source value can be exactly
>   represented in the destination type, the result of the conversion is
>   that exact representation. If the source value is between two adjacent
>   destination values, the result of the conversion is an
>   implementation-defined choice of either of those values. Otherwise,
>   the behavior is undefined.

We can read more details on the implications of this in [GotW #67: double or nothing](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/067.htm) which says:

> This means that a double constant can be implicitly (i.e., silently)
>   converted to a float constant, even if doing so loses precision (i.e.,
>   data). This was allowed to remain for C compatibility and usability
>   reasons, but it's worth keeping in mind when you do floating-point
>   work.
>
> A quality compiler will warn you if you try to do something that's
>   undefined behavior, namely put a double quantity into a float that's
>   less than the minimum, or greater than the maximum, value that a float
>   is able to represent. A really good compiler will provide an optional
>   warning if you try to do something that may be defined but could lose
>   information, namely put a double quantity into a float that is between
>   the minimum and maximum values representable by a float, but which
>   can't be represented exactly as a float.

So there are caveats for the general case that you should be aware of.

From a practical perspective, in this case the results will *most likely* be the same even though technically there is a conversion, we can see this by trying out the following code on [godbolt](http://gcc.godbolt.org/):

```
#include <iostream>

float func1()
{
  return 3.0; // a double literal
}


float func2()
{
  return 3.0f ; // a float literal
}

int main()
{  
  std::cout << func1() << ":" << func2() << std::endl ;
  return 0;
}
```

and we see that the results for `func1` and `func2` are identical, using both `clang` and `gcc`:

```
func1():
    movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR .LC0[rip]
    ret
func2():
    movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR .LC0[rip]
    ret
```

As [Pascal points out in this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25229832/is-float-a-3-0-a-correct-statement#comment39304567_25229950) you won't always be able to count on this. Using `0.1` and `0.1f` respectively causes the assembly generated to differ since the conversion must now be done explicitly. The following code:

```
float func1(float x )
{
  return x*0.1; // a double literal
}

float func2(float x)
{
  return x*0.1f ; // a float literal
}
```

results in the following assembly:

```
func1(float):  
    cvtss2sd    %xmm0, %xmm0    # x, D.31147    
    mulsd   .LC0(%rip), %xmm0   #, D.31147
    cvtsd2ss    %xmm0, %xmm0    # D.31147, D.31148
    ret
func2(float):
    mulss   .LC2(%rip), %xmm0   #, D.31155
    ret
```

Regardless whether you can determine if the conversion will have a performance impact or not, using the correct type better documents your intention. Using an explicit conversions for example `static_cast` also helps to clarify the conversion was intended as opposed to accidental, which may signify a bug or potential bug.

**Note**

As supercat points out, multiplication by e.g. `0.1` and `0.1f` is not equivalent. I am just going to quote the comment because it was excellent and a summary probably would not do it justice:

> For example, if f was equal to 100000224 (which is exactly
>   representable as a float), multiplying it by one tenth should yield a
>   result which rounds down to 10000022, but multiplying by 0.1f will
>   instead yield a result which erroneously rounds up to 10000023. If the
>   intention is to divide by ten, multiplication by double constant 0.1
>   will likely be faster than division by 10f, and more precise than
>   multiplication by 0.1f.

My original point was to demonstrate a false example given in another question but this  finely demonstrates subtle issues can exist in toy examples.

Comment: It may be worth noting that the expressions `f = f * 0.1;` and `f = f * 0.1f;` *do different things*.  For example, if `f` was equal to 100000224 (which is exactly representable as a `float`), multiplying it by one tenth should yield a result which rounds down to 10000022, but multiplying by 0.1f will instead yield a result which erroneously rounds up to 10000023.  If the intention is to divide by ten, multiplication by `double` constant 0.1 will likely be faster than division by `10f`, and more precise than multiplication by `0.1f`.

Comment: @supercat thank you for the nice example, I quoted you directly, please feel free to edit as you see fit.

Answer (score 4):

It's not an error in the sense that the compiler will reject it, but it is an error in the sense that it may not be what you want.

As your book correctly states, `3.0` is a value of type `double`. There is an implicit conversion from `double` to `float`, so `float a = 3.0;` is a valid definition of a variable.

However, at least conceptually, this performs a needless conversion. Depending on the compiler, the conversion may be performed at compile time, or it may be saved for run time. A valid reason for saving it for run time is that floating-point conversions are difficult and may have unexpected side effects if the value cannot be represented exactly, and it's not always easy to verify whether the value can be represented exactly.

`3.0f` avoids that problem: although technically, the compiler is still allowed to calculate the constant at run time (it always is), here, there is absolutely no reason why any compiler might possibly do that.

Comment: Indeed, in the case of a cross-compiler it would be quite incorrect for the conversion to be performed at compile time, because it would be happening on the wrong platform.

Answer (score 2):

While not an error, per se, it is a little sloppy. You know you want a float, so initialize it with a float.
Another programmer may come along and not be sure which part of the declaration is correct, the type or the initializer. Why not have them both be correct?
    float Answer = 42.0f;

Answer (score 0):

When you define a variable, it is initialized with the provided initializer. This may require converting the value of the initializer to the type of the variable that's being initialized. That's what's happening when you say `float a = 3.0;`: The value of the initializer is converted to `float`, and the result of the conversion becomes the initial value of `a`.

That's generally fine, but it doesn't hurt to write `3.0f` to show that you're aware of what you're doing, and especially if you want to write `auto a = 3.0f`.

Answer (score 0):

If you try out the following:

```
std::cout << sizeof(3.2f) <<":" << sizeof(3.2) << std::endl;
```

you will get output as:

```
4:8
```

that shows, size of 3.2f is taken as 4 bytes on 32-bit machine wheres 3.2 is interpreted as double value taking 8 bytes on 32-bit machine.
This should provide the answer that you are looking for.

Comment: That shows that `double` and `float` are different, it doesn't answer whether you can initialize a `float` from a double literal

Comment: of course you can initialize a float from a double value subject to data truncation, if applicable

Comment: Yes, I know, but that was the OP's question, so your answer failed to actually answer it, despite claiming to provide the answer!

Answer (score 0):

The compiler deduces the best-fitting type from literals, or at leas what it thinks is best-fitting. That is rather lose efficiency over precision, i.e. use a double instead of float.
If in doubt, use brace-intializers to make it explicit:

```
auto d = double{3}; // make a double
auto f = float{3}; // make a float
auto i = int{3}; // make a int
```

The story gets more interesting if you initialize from another variable where type-conversion rules apply: While it is legal to constuct  a double form a literal, it cant be contructed from an int without possible narrowing:

```
auto xxx = double{i} // warning ! narrowing conversion of 'i' from 'int' to 'double'
```

Answer (score 0):

> is that an error?

Appending an `f` to the constant can result in [different values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66631288/2410359) for `float a`.

```
float a = 10000000.5000000001;
// `a` has the value of  10000000.0 (or 0x1.312d00p+23)

float a = 10000000.5000000001f;
// `a` has the value of  10000001.0 (or 0x1.312d02p+23)
```

If that difference is important, then yes, code has an error.
Usually the constant with the `f` is preferred when initializing a `float`.

A difference occurs because
`float a = 10000000.5000000001;` goes through 2 roundings (text --> `double` --> `float`) and
`float a = 10000000.5000000001f;` goes through 1 rounding (text --> `float`) and
the first incurred [double rounding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Double_rounding).