# Where does 1.0f and 1.0 makes difference?

Tags: c

While studying about video compression encoder I came across float rateRatio=1.0f. I want know where does it make difference I mean 1.0f and 1.0?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between 2.0 and 2.0f (explicit float vs double literals)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3696902/difference-between-2-0-and-2-0f-explicit-float-vs-double-literals)

Comment: it makes a difference in expressions not involving double types: the 1.0f is of type float so it calculates the expression using floats instead of doubles, which is potentially faster

Comment: In `float rateRatio=1.0f` the suffix is useless, because the value is assigned to `float`.

Comment: It's not a duplicate, the question does not ask the difference between  `1.0f` and `1.0` but where does it make a difference. See my answer.

Comment: Related to [Is 'float a = 3.0;' a correct statement?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25229832/1708801) in my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25231230/1708801) I cover some interesting cases.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As other said, one literal is of type `float` and the other is of type `double`.
Here is an example where it makes a difference:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a = 16777217 * 1.0f;
    int b = 16777217 * 1.0;

    printf("%d %d\n", a, b);
}
```

prints on my machine:

```
16777216 16777217
```

The expression `16777217 * 1.0f` is of type `float` and `16777217` cannot be represented exactly in a `float` (in IEEE-754) while it can be represented exactly in a `double`.

Answer (score 7):

One is a `double` the other is a `float`:

```
double x = 0.0;  // denotes a double
float y  = 0.0f; // denotes a float
```

It depends on the system but e.g. on Windows you'll find that `float` has 32bit of precision whereas `double` has 64bit. This can make a tremendous difference when it comes to precise or numericable unstable calculations.

Comment: @PRAVINPAWAR ther's an implicit conversion between `double` and `float`, but if the compiler can't compute it at compile-time it will be a runtime cast.

Comment: @PRAVINPAWAR see ouah's answer

Answer (score 6):

> can we not write float y=0.0

From your comment, I see where the confusion stems from. It's not the data type of the variable assigned to but the data type of literal constant (0.0, 1.0f, 1.0, etc.) itself that matters here. When you write

```
float f = 1.0;
```

`1.0` a literal of type `double` while `f` is a `float`, hence the compiler does an implicit narrowing conversion to `float`, the same holds true for `double d = 1.0f` where it's widening implicit conversion from `float` to `double`.

[Implicit conversion rules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23873536/183120) are the reason `16777217 * 1.0f` expression (in *ouah*'s answer) becomes a `float`, since `1.0f` is a `float` and in an expression with both `float` and `int` the resulting type is dictated by the standard as a `float`, thus both are converted to `float`s, but the resulting value isn't representable as a `float` and thus you see a different value.

Instead when `1.0f` is changed into `1.0` it becomes a `double` and thus `16777217 * 1.0` expression becomes a `double` (again because the standard dictates that in an expression with double and any other integral type, the result is a  `double`) which is large enough to hold the value `16777217`.