# C++ does not take 5/9 and seems to typecast it

Tags: c++

Why does

```
 float bla = ( 5/9 )* (100 - 32) result in 0 * 100 -> 0 ?
```

and

```
float bla= 5*(100- 32) / 9;
```

work out?
He seems to see 5/9 as a integer and make it to 0 immidiatly but the result variable is a float so the compiler should know he can work with 5/9 or?

Comment: Because math is evaluated left to right.

Comment: `(5/9)` is integer division. It doesn't matter that you're storing the result in a `float`.

Comment: (5/9) == 0 because of integer division.

Comment: The second one is incorrect as well. You are converting a rounded integer to float. The second gives 37, whereas the correct answer is: 37.7778

Answer (score 9):

Use the correct literals so you get the correct mathematical behavior

```
float bla = 5.0f * (100.0f - 32.0f) / 9.0f;
```

Note the following brief list

```
5      // int
5l     // long
5.0    // double
5.0f   // float
5ul    // unsigned long
```

A more comprehensive list of [integer literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal) and [floating point literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/floating_literal)

In your example, the entire right hand side is performed in `int` operations, then the final result is implicitly converted to `float`. By then it is too late.

Remember, [using the correct literal is important](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25229832/is-float-a-3-0-a-correct-statement)!

Comment: Thanks, i will accept the answer as far as it is possibke

Comment: @Etixpp also note that `double` will be implicitly converted to `float` too. That makes for cleaner looking constants, although it forces the math to occur at `double` resolution.

Answer (score 2):

> He seems to see 5/9 as a integer and make it to 0 immidiatly

That's right; the result of integer division is an integer.

> but the result variable is a float so the compiler should know he can work with 5/9 or?

No, the type of an expression never depends on what's done with it afterwards. If it needs converting to another type, that happens after the expression is evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
float bla = ( (float)5/9 )* (100 - 32)
```

Because when you do `5/9`, you do an integer division, that results 0. If you want a float division, make a cast in the elements of the division.

Comment: Or `5.0/9.0`, which IMHO is clearer.

Comment: Yes, but you question is `why`, so I'm showing you are doing a integer division. If you use 5. or 5f, you are doing a float division. Image that you are using variables. You cannot put `f` after the literal, you should use the cast.

Comment: @KeithThompson `5.0f/9.0f`?

Comment: No. `int i = 5; int j = 9; float bla = i/j;`

Comment: @dlf: Either way. `5.0` is of type `double`; the result will be converted to `float` when it's assigned to `bla`. It *probably* doesn't matter.

Comment: @KeithThompson Yup; *probably* not. :)

Comment: Using float-point literals rather than casts makes sense *for this example*, which happens to be using constant values. (`5/9` looks like it could be part of a temperature conversion.) If `5` is replaced by an `int` variable, then yes, a cast would be necessary -- or, more likely, that variable should have been defined as a `float` in the first place. The context matters, and we don't know enough about the context from the code in the question. IMHO it's worth mentioning both possibilities.

Comment: The result is defined as float. The question doesn't say anything about the other values.

Answer (score 1):

The `float` type is on the other side of the equation - so the conversion to a `float` won't happen until *after* the expression on the right side has been evaluated. Since all of those variables are integers the arithmetic will not be floating-point. Convert at least one to a `float` and it should behave as expected.

Comment: It's important *which* one you convert to `float`. `(5/9.0)*(100-32)` would work, as would `(5.0/9)*(100-32)`, but `(5/9)*(100.0-32)` would *not*.

Answer (score 1):

In order to prevent constants treated as integers, write down such calculations as:

```
float bla = ( 5./9. )* (100. - 32.);
```

Comment: These are `double` literals, not `float`.

Comment: You are correct. The precision is here reduced by the cast to float, but the answer is correct.

Comment: Yes; it would rarely matter, but I figured it was at least worth noting.

Answer (score 1):

The key here is integer division. `5/9` is equal to approximately `0.55555...`, but in integer division the decimals get cut off. So really, its just `0`. Thus we have

```
0 * (100-32) -> 0
```

Where as `5*(100-32)/9` appears to work out because `100-32=68`, `68*5=340` and `340/9 = 37.777...` which is rounded down to 37. So in reality, you are still getting an "incorrect" answer, but it is non-zero so it appears to be valid at a glance.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are doing integer arithmetic in which `5/9 == 0`

In your first example

```
float bla = 5/9 * (100-32)
          = 0 * (100-32)
          = 0
```

The second however:

```
float bla= 5*(100- 32) / 9;
         = 5*68 / 9
         = 340 / 9
         = 37
```

Both are incorrect due to the integer divide. The second should be 37.77777

To fix it change the values to floats:

```
float bla= 5.0f/9.0f * (100-32)
```