# When to use instance variables instead of properties in objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, properties, instance-variables

With the Objective-C's @property directive I can declare properties for which getter and setter methods will be created automatically. I can't think of any particular reason to use instance variables where I would have to write my own setter and getters, but I'm sure there must be an example where using instance variables is more preferable. Could there be any reason to use instance variables instead of properties? Are there any practical examples for it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ does not take 5/9 and seems to typecast it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27971967/c-does-not-take-5-9-and-seems-to-typecast-it)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is on this line

```
slope = (line_cordinates[3] - line_cordinates[1]) / (line_cordinates[2] - line_cordinates[0]);
```

`slope` is declared a `float`, but `line_cordinates` is an array of `int`.

So you are doing all of the math on the right hand side as `int` math, then assigning it to a `float`. So the final result of all the `int` operations is implicitly converted to `float`, but by then you have already lost the precision from truncation, etc.

The quickest fix would be to simply declare

```
float line_cordinates[4] = {0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0};
```

Answer (score 2):

Use,

```
slope = static_cast<float>((line_cordinates[3] - line_cordinates[1])) / (line_cordinates[2] - line_cordinates[0]);
```

You need to typecast any of the operand on right hand side to float. So expression will result in float.

int op int = int
float op int = float