# Arithmetic calculation anomaly

Tags: c++, math, visual-c++, arithmetic-expressions

I was trying to solve [this exercise](https://www.codeabbey.com/index/task_view/fahrenheit-celsius). Here is the solution:

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;

int main()
{
    int n, a;
    cin >> n;
    int* answers = new int[n]; // allocating memory
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> a;
        answers[i] = (a - 32) * 5/9;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << answers[i] << ' ';
    }

    cout << '\n';
    delete[]answers; //deallocating memory

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Now, notice when I change `answers[i] = (a - 32) * 5/9;` to `answers[i] = (a - 32) * (5/9);`. 
Here, is the difference in the output respectively:

1. Without the brackets:

   [image]
2. With the brackets:

   [image]

**What is this sorcery?**

**EDIT:**

I understand why this can seem as a duplicate. My concern is not why 5/9 outputs 0. That is not my concern. My concern is what is the difference between the two following code:

- `answers[i] = (a - 32) * 5/9;`
- `answers[i] = (a - 32) * (5/9);`

When I do not use brackets, it works. But, when I use brackets it just outputs 0. So, the question is what is the bracket operator changing here? Please read the question carefully.

Comment: `5/9` -- What is this equal to?

Comment: It's much better to using `std::vector` instead of raw array.

Comment: *What is this sorcery?* -- What is surprising is that you have a relatively high rep count (135), but didn't know about integer division in C++ (which should be covered in chapter 1 of any C++ book).  Hopefully you're not learning C++ from bad websites or bad tutorials.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie It equates to 0.55555555555556

Comment: @ProgrammingRage No it doesn't.  Maybe on your calculator it does, but C++ is not a calculator.  Try `std::cout << 5/9;` and see what is outputted.

Comment: @GhasemRamezani I agree, but I have not touched STL yet in my learning.

Comment: @churill Which answer in the question do you think answers my question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ does not take 5/9 and seems to typecast it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27971967/c-does-not-take-5-9-and-seems-to-typecast-it)

Comment: @phuclv No, I am trying to understand what is the bracket operator changing? I know 5/9 outputs 0 because of integer. But why does 5/9 work and (5/9) not work?

Comment: @ProgrammingRage The bracket operator totally changes the math.  Without the brackets, you are multiplying `(a-32)` by 5.  It may be an eye thing, but look more closely.

Comment: @ProgrammingRage None, I see your question has a different focus now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `(a - 32) * 5/9;` the expression is done from **left to right** as `((a - 32) * 5)/9` because `*` and `/` have the [same precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) with left-to-right [associativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_associativity)

If you do `(a - 32) * (5/9)` then it's exactly the same as `(a - 32) * 0` because the expressions in `()` are done first, and `5/9` is an integer division that results in 0. To do a floating-point division then at least one side of the division must be a floating-point type. Try `(a - 32) * (5.0/9)` or `(a - 32) * (5/9.0)` and see

Answer (score 2):

According to the C++ `5 / 9` is 0, because 5 and 9 are integers.
You should use double.

```
int main()
{
    int n, a;
    cin >> n;
    int* answers = new int[n]; // allocating memory
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> a;
        answers[i] = (a - 32) * 5/9.0; // 9.0 is double
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << answers[i] << ' ';
    }

    cout << '\n';
    delete[]answers; //deallocating memory

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you allocate a float array to put the number into?

Comment: If that is the case, why does (5/9) not work and 5/9 work?

Answer (score 1):

With the brackets you are evaluated (int) 5 / 9 which is 0.  Without the brackets, you are seeing the effect of * and / having the same operator precedence and they are evaluated left to right which means the expression would be evaluated as ((a - 32) * 5) / 9.

If you are doing fractional math, you usually assign the value to a floating point type (float, double etc).  If you want indeed want the result as an int, you may still want to do the calculation as a floating point, and you usually do that implicitly by making one of the constants a floating point type like 5.0 / 9.